# Minimum power to pull a sheet of paper

Tags: kinematics

I'm trying to tackle a question in kinematics, but I miss something and don't know what.

The question goes like this:

> Let a homogeneous pole of mass m be connected to ceiling and lean on the floor (the floor has no friction). The pole creates an angle of $\alpha$ degrees with the perpendicular line to the floor. Let some sheet of paper be inserted between the pole and the floor. The friction coefficient between the pole and the paper is $\mu$.
>
> A. what is the minimal power that is needed to pull the paper to the right?

I have a drawing of the question:

[image]

My Try:

I have drawn a Cartesian system through the center of mass.
While the pole is not moving, then:
$\sum f_y=N_1+N_2-mg=0$ where $N_1$ is the normal force that the ceiling is causing and $N_2$ is the force that the paper is causing.

I understand that if we are trying to pull the paper to the the right, then the friction will act to the left, so I need to demand that $F>f$.

At this point I'm stuck. Also, what will happen if I want to pull the paper to the left?

Please help, thank you. And sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the torques is zero, $\sum \tau =0$. Thus, since the centre of mass is in the middle of the pole, that's where the weight $W$ will act. $F_y$, is the normal force exerted by the pole on the paper. We have:
$$mg\frac{l}{2}\sin{\alpha}-F_y\ l\sin{\alpha}=0$$
Hence, the normal force $F_y=\frac{mg}{2}$. Friction is given by $f=\mu N$, and so the minimum force required to move the paper to the right is $\frac{mg\mu}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you! The same is happening when I want to move the paper to the left, right?